# Como se hace la comunicación entre fragment y activity y viceversa?

Tags: android-studio, android-fragment

Ya llevo 2 días buscando y no encuentro una respuesta clara, ya leí todas las respuestas que Google me muestra y no logro entender.

Para ser más específico, parte de la aplicación que estoy haciendo contiene 3 formularios de registro para el cliente donde el lo tiene que completar con su nombre, apellido, fecha de nacimiento, género, ocupación, dirección de domicilio, etc y esos formularios están hechos en Fragments, mi problema radica en que no se cómo puedo pasar toda esa información al activity principal que lo aloja al fragment, alguien por favor que me ayude

Answer (score -1):

Hay varias formas por ejemplo podridas crear un clase que almacene los campos que usaras ok?
 en tu activity podria quedar asi

```
private claseContenedora contendedora;
```

y crear un metodo publico en tu activity

```
public void setClaseContendedora(claseContenedora contendedora){
this.contendedora = contendedora;
}
```

en el ultimo fragment de tu formulario llamas al método y seteas los valores con un boton de finalizar o con lo que desees concluir

```
((Nombredetuactividad) getActivity()).setClaseContenedora(contenedora);
```

Otra forma es usar Serializable junto a sharedpreferences

Comment: Gracias por tus contribuciones pero es recomendable que las preguntas a responder sean realizadas en base a [ask] de otra forma estas contribuyendo a agrega contenido de baja calidad al sitio.

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder, tengo una duda, porque en el último Fragment debo llamar al método? Porque no en cada fragment? ya que cada uno de los fragment tienen datos ingresados por el cliente y que se debe capturar.

Comment: Claro los fragment deben enviarse la información entre si, intenta reformular tu pregunta